# Export multilingual settings with features

Tags: 7, features, i18n-l10n

I'm using features to export 10 content types, but I don't get the multilingual settings. My question is, whether this is even possible, maybe with strongarm or I'm stuck having to change those settings by hand?

I use the i18n module and want the content_type to be translatable, in the content_type edit menu i set:

- Publishing Settings->Multilingual Settings-> Enable with Translation
- Multilingual Settings->Extended language options->Require language (Do not allow Language Neutral).

Comment: which multilingual settings ? (where do you set them, which modules do you use ?)

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can do this with Strongarm.  You'll want to add all the variables that are prefixed `i18n_`, `language_`, and `locale_`.

Comment: this is even with strongarm and features a cumbersome solution. I find the blob fields in drupal pretty difficult to handle with